# Is it possible to express $\sqrt{2}-1$ as the sum of a positive rational and a positive irrational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let us denote $\sqrt2= r+z$  where $r$ is the integer part of $\sqrt2$ i.e. $r=1$, and $z=\sqrt2-1$, the irrational part of $\sqrt2$.

Question: is it possible to express $z$ as the sum of two positive numbers, the one being rational and the other irrational?

Comment: What about $z=\frac14+\left(z-\frac14\right)$?

Comment: Yes, this is a trivial task. You could do
$$
z = \frac{2}{5} + 0.0142135\ldots
$$

Comment: If it helps in searches, $z$ here is usually called the fractional part of $\sqrt{2}$ rather than the irrational part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can in infinitely many ways.

Adding to @JoséCarlosSantos and @MattiP. ‘s comments, we would express $\sqrt{2}$ as:

$\sqrt{2} = n + (\sqrt{2} - n)$, where you could choose $n$ as any number $n \in \mathbb Q$.

Here, $n$ is rational (by definition), and $\sqrt{2} - n$ will be irrational, which follows from the fact that $\text{irrational} - \text{rational} = \text{irrational}$ always.

Of course, this works as $n + (\sqrt{2} - n) = n + \sqrt{2} - n = \not n + \sqrt{2} - \not n = \sqrt{2}$.

If you prefer decimal,

$\sqrt{2} = 1 + 0.41421356237…$ where $0.41421356237$ is irrational.

This applies to the general case, where:

$z = t + (z - t)$ where $z$ is the irrational number and $t$ is any rational.

---

To express $z = \sqrt{2} - 1$ as $\text{rational} + \text{irrational}$, we could simply take:

$z = \frac{4}{10} + (\sqrt{2} - 1 - \frac{4}{10})$, where $\sqrt{2} - 1 - \frac{4}{10}$ is considered a single value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but n+$\sqrt2$-n is not the sum of two numbers but the sum of three numbers, of n, $\sqrt2$, and (-n).

Comment: @Kostas We would count $(z - t)$ a single constant, just written as a difference of the two others. If you’d like some other perspective, let me know.

Comment: I thank you all for your answers, all very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple: any positive irrational number $z$ can be expressed (in infinitely many ways) as $z=q+x$, where q is a positive rational number and $x$ is a positive irrational number.

Simply choose $q$ to be any positive rational that is less than $z$, and let
$x=z-q$.

If you want an explicit formula for such a $q$:
$$q=1/(\lfloor 1/z\rfloor + 1)$$